# R caret / rfe / bayesglm feature selection

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe, bayesglm

I'm using `bayesglm` for a logistic regression problem.  It's a dataset of 150 rows and 2000 variables.  I'm trying to do variable selection and usually look at `glmnet` in `caret::rfe`.  However there isn't a method for `bayesglm`.

Is there anyway to manually define a method for `rfe`?

Comment: Can you specify is feature selection involves rfeControl() you want to do rfe? and (from caret manual) _Examples of these functions are included in the package: lmFuncs, rfFuncs, treebagFuncs and
nbFuncs._, there are no bayesglm functions? Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the the question I can only think of rewriting `lmFuncs$fit` function, for example:

```
lmFuncs$fit<-function (x, y, first, last, ...){   
     tmp <- as.data.frame(x)   
     tmp$y <- y   
 bayesglm (y ~ ., family = gaussian, data = tmp)
}
```

and then do your `rfe.fit` with `rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs)`

Comment: awesome.  I didn't know you could rewrite the functions.  thank you very much.

Comment: Hope it will do the trick! I use caret for feature selection but instead of rewriting functions I use all possible regression/classification training methods available from caret and then I call either rfe() function or predict() with fitted model. And then I assume which features to explicit from final model (mostly ANN).